# Getting The Result Of An AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the result of the asynctask by using an interface but when I've tried to use the methods on that interface my app keeps on crashing.

This project has 4 java files: **MainActivity.java** , **SigninActivity.java** , **GetAvailableExam.java** , **AsyncResponse.java**

I'm pretty sure the error is not on the **GetAvailableExam.java** because it is just an activity that prints hello world so I'm not going to post it's code here, also I'm going to trim the whole code and post only the code that I think is relevant to this problem.

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    role = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    method = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    signinactivity.delegate = this;
}

public void processFinish(String output){
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**SigninActivity.java**

```
//global variables
private TextView statusField,roleField;
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost = 0;
private String server_ip;
private ProgressDialog progress;
public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    this.statusField.setText("Login Successful");
    this.roleField.setText(result);
    this.progress.dismiss(); 
    delegate.processFinish(result);
}
```

**AsyncResponse.java**

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

The delegate.processFinish(result) on the **SigninActivity.java** is the one causing the crash, The app works fine if I try to remove/comment out it.

Additionally I just want to ask why this code does not work?

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    this.statusField.setText("Login Successful");
    this.roleField.setText(result);
    this.progress.dismiss();

    if(result=="student") {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, GetAvailableExam.class));
    }
}
```

The point of the whole question is to open an activity if the result is satisfied, but the code above does not work if I try to add an if condition on it.

If someone is interested in seeing the whole code I've already posted it [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/coding/java-android/help-finding-cause-crash-code-t2989214)

Comment: Well you didn't post the crash, but I assume its a null pointer exception because delegate is null.  Why are you manipulating public member variables of 1 activity from another?  That's almost certainly a sign of bad design.  And since its a non-static member, how are you even getting a valid copy of the signinactivity in mainactivity?

Comment: Well I saw it here on stackoverflow as an accepted answer so I assume that it will work on me.

Comment: Using an interface like that is an accepted way of doing things (see Rajen's example below for the right way to do it).  Using a variable in a second activity like that is NOT.  Its a failure in encapsulation and will make your code difficult to maintain.  Why would you ever want to tie two activities together like that?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking I'm just starting to develop on android and I'm having a hard time in grasping your terminologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way

```
if(result.equals("student")) {
```

used `.equals()` method for `string comparison`

Comment: Well this works first but I demand an explanation why .equals and == works differently lol

Comment: @ClonedAccnt Because `==` is an `Operator` and works only in `Integer` values.So...

Comment: Oh that's why, I'm a php programmer and we use == both on numerical and string but anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sample example considering your context.

```
public class AsyncOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    AsyncResponse delegate; //Here it is your interface instance
    public AsyncOperation (AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String result;
       // Do your processing here.
       return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.equals("Student")){
            // do your processing.
        }
    }
}
```

Here in this approach you will never have your interface delegate null as you are passing to your AsycnOperation constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the wrong use of `==` as "M D" said, the way you're doing the delegate is a bit odd.

At the least, check that it is not null:

```
if (delegate!=null) {
    delegate.processFinish(result);
}
```

You may think "but it will always be non null", but that is dependent on the execution sequence.

Overall I think there will be a cleaner way that removes the approach you're using.